# Javascript: Why do I need to declare var i = 0 in the for loop?

Tags: javascript

I was doing a problem that required recursion, for counting coin combinations that add up to a certain amount. The solution that works is below. One thing that bothered me for hours was that when i did not declare var i = 0 in the for loop, it doesn't work. As I understand when I declare var in the for loop it stays within that scope where as if i don't it is pulling it from the global? Can someone explain to me why this algorithm doesn't work on jsfiddle.net unless I declare var i = 0 in the for loop. Thanks to anyone who can help.

```
var coins = [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100];
var ways = 0;

function combo(index,amount) {
    //if I write for(i=0;...;i++) it doesn't work 
    for (var i = 0; i <= Math.ceil(amount / coins[index]); i++) {
        amountleft = amount - (i * coins[index]);
        if (amount < 0) {
            break;
        }
        if (amountleft == 0) {
            ways ++;
            break;
        }
        if (amountleft > 0) {
            combo(index + 1,amountleft);
        }
    }
}    


combo(0,50)
console.log(ways)
```

Comment: Do you have `'use strict';` at the beginning of your code?

Comment: it should work in regular js, but not the strict subset...

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Your assumption is correct. If `var` is omitted, the variable will be global (or throw an error, depending on your browser).

If your function is recursive, there will obviously be interference when the loops from different places in the stack are changing (and relying on, for iteration) the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

Its scoped to the function not the for-loop block. some people put it outside. It has the same effect both ways.

```
var i = 0;
for (; i<foo.length; i++) {
}
```

You should always use `var` when declaring variables in es5. It is worth reading up on how it is scoped (hint: usually to the function its declared in). In es6 we have `let` which is scoped to the block its declared in (in this case the for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Because in javascript you have to explicit declare your variable before you want to use it. So if you write

```
for(i=0;...;i++)
```

where is the variable `i` come from? Javascript will throw error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah of-course it won't work, `i` is variable and it has to be initialized.

And yes you can declare it outside for loop. But i think you had declared it outside the function which will not work.

```
function combo(index,amount) {
var i;
for (i = 0; i <= Math.ceil(amount / coins[index]); i++) {
    amountleft = amount - (i * coins[index]);
    if (amount < 0) {
        break;
    }
    if (amountleft == 0) {
        ways ++;
        break;
    }
    if (amountleft > 0) {
        combo(index + 1,amountleft);
    }
}
}
```